# Lower bound on largest singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

I was generating random matrices in Mathematica and noticed that the largest singular value $\sigma_\max$ is always greater than the largest entry of the matrix. I.e., for a matrix $A=\left(a_{ij}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$
$$\sigma_\max \geq a_{ij}\quad \text{ for all }\;i,j$$

Unfortunantly I have no idea how to prove this fact (if it's true) and what does it mean. I'll apreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known (and stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Applications), for example) that 
$$
\sigma_{max}(A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|
$$
Thus: for any $i,j$: if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denotes the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$, we have
$$
\sigma_{max}(A) \geq \|A e_j\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}^2} \geq \sqrt{a_{ij}^2} = |a_{ij}|
$$
Thus, we get the desired inequality.